# iOS-NSArray filter having condition

Tags: nsarray

I'm new here!

I have an `NSArray` like this `("file01_header","file01_body", "file01_xxx", ... ,"file02_header", ...)`.

I filter it and get 2 distinct NSArrays:

1. Array_header `("file01_header","file02_header",...)`
2. Array_body
   `("file01_body", "file02_body", ...)`

now I have to subtract from Array_header all the items that have a corresponding one in Array_body, because not all items have a `fileNN_body` for the `fileNN_header` in the original array, and I have to give the Array_header as output with only items that has no corresponding body.

How can I do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using swift you can filter pretty easily using a closure and some minor string-fu.

Here's an example:

```
let funkyArray = ["file01_header","file01_body", "file01_xxx", "file02_header","file03_xxx"]

let headerFilterClosure : (String) -> Bool = {fileName in
    if fileName.containsString("header") {
        let fileBase = fileName.componentsSeparatedByString("_")[0]
        let fileBodyName = "\(fileBase)_body"

        if funkyArray.contains(fileBodyName) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

funkyArray.filter(headerFilterClosure)
```

I think a better long term solution would be to not have such a funky array and use a data structure or at least a tuple with options to manage your file info.

Best,
Josh

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I don't use swift and I have to use that funky array I have no choice :(